# How can force redirected to login page, if any visitor view or access to specific pages - WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a multiple author wordpress blog. I want to force redirected to login page, if any visitor view or access to specific pages. example : If user visit to specific page like, www.mysite.com/author-terms/, thereafter redirect to www.mysite.com/wp-admin.php/. Thanks in advance.

We have created a page in our blog called 'Instructions for Contributors', like; https://example.com/instruction/. If any visitor copied the link to this page ('Instructions for Contributors') and opens it directly in the browser. So it will open, and anyone can read the instructions given in it. Want to limit it to the blog's contributors. If a visitor tries to open the 'Instructions for Writers' page link directly, then it is redirected directly to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
   <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // if you wish user info?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="/wp-login.php" title="Members Area Login" rel="home">Members Area</a>
<?php } ?>
```

put this page into your specific page template. :) coding

Comment: Respected Sir, I am grateful to you for your cooperation. But can you give me any suggestion to inject me into function.php. Because I have basic knowledge of WordPress coding.